# Processing order of events "mousedown, mouseup,click" & timeout in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, event-loop

after studying several pages about event-loop, message queue, javascript stack etc. I tried the following:

```html
<html><head></head>
<body>
<div id="parent">
 <div id="child">
  <span id ="span">
   <p id="innerP">
    Click Me!
   </p>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
<div id ="text">
</div>

<script>
var innerP = document.getElementById('innerP');
var span = document.getElementById('span');
var child = document.getElementById('child');
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var text = document.getElementById('text');

function eventHandler(oEvent){
 var id = oEvent.currentTarget.id;
 var type = oEvent.type;

 text.textContent += oEvent.type + ": " + oEvent.currentTarget.id + ", ";
  setTimeout(function(){
  text.textContent += "CLICK TIMEOUT: "+id+","+type+", ";
 },0);
}

innerP.onclick = eventHandler;
span.onclick = eventHandler;
child.onclick = eventHandler;
parent.onclick = eventHandler;

innerP.onmousedown = eventHandler;
span.onmousedown = eventHandler;
child.onmousedown = eventHandler;
parent.onmousedown = eventHandler;

innerP.onmouseup = eventHandler;
span.onmouseup = eventHandler;
child.onmouseup = eventHandler;
parent.onmouseup = eventHandler;

</script></body></html>
```

I noticed that the timeouts set by mousedown event will be processed right after the mousedown block (DOM bubbling), but the timeouts for mouseup get processed after mouseup and click block.

Assumption?
Does chrome remember the DOM propagation path, so that mouseup and click gets processed earlier in task/ message queue of the event loop in the main thread?

Thanks,
Daniel